# How can I use \multirow and \multicolumn simultaniously?

Tags: multicol, multirow

I want to make below table using latex. But I don't know how to combine \multirow and \multicolumn. How can I make below table using latex?

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: I see no need for `\multirow`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for `\multirow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{C{.5in}|}}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries 2} \\
\cline{2-5}
  & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
1 & A & A & A & A \\
\hline
2 & B & B & B & B \\
\hline
3 & C & C & C & C \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `\usepackage{tabularx,multirow}`. Here is an example of a table mixing `\multicolumn{numberOfColumns}{position}{text}` and `\multirow{numberOfrows}{*}{text}` (* to use the natural width of the contents or directly enter the width of the cell).

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \caption{caption}
  \begin{tabular}{lc c r l r l}
    \hline
    col1 & col2 & col3 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{col4} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{col5} \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{multirow1} & row1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{--} \\
                               & row2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{multirow2} & row1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{--} \\
                               & row2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab1}
\end{table}
```

[image]